# invokeOnClick checkbox in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Coud somebody tell me, how can I invoke onClick Event of checkBox1 in visual c++?
I'm using MS Visual c++ studio 2010 express.

maby someone know how to use Invoke(Delegate) or InvokeOnClick methods

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SendMessage` or `SendDlgItemMessage` function. This is Win32 API.